# Onbackpressed close app not closing app after login

Tags: android, android-fragments, onbackpressed

My application consist of 2 main activity and 1 secondary activity (login popup)

1. Activity is PreLogin activity where user have application info and few other things and button for login. When he presses that button, new activity starts as a popup. And if he clicks back there, that activity is closed and user is returned to previous activity.
2. Activity is PostLogin and there I implemented this function:

My code:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
        return;
    }

    this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
    final View coordinatorLayoutView = findViewById(R.id.coordinator);

    Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayoutView, "Press again to exit.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {


        @Override
        public void run() {
            doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;

        }
    }, 5000);
}
```

This code should close my application but problem is that pressing back button 2 times, the grey screen shows and users need to click back button once more to exit the app.

I'm quite sure problem is somehow connected with my Prelogin activity because when I try `noHistory` on my Prelogin activity `onBackpressed()` worked like charm but I can't use that approach because I need to have history on my Prelogin so back button work for Login Popup.

Comment: Can you please tell why did you add the `android-fragments` tag? I don't see where it is related to fragments. Mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the simple code below to achieve that.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (back_pressed + 2000 > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
            //Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            //intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            //intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            //startActivity(intent);
            super.onBackPressed();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Press the back button once again to close the application.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            back_pressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
    }
```

Here, `2000` is `2 Seconds`, you can change it to whatever value you like. If the back button is pressed within `2 seconds` again, then only it will go back.

You can call the `Intent` of the previous activity if you want, or you can remove the commented `Intent` code to go back to the `Home` Screen.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put finish(); after startActivity(intent); on the first Activity!

Answer (score 0):

Call finish() method in your first activity (login activity) after starting intent.